# Why cannot invokeLater method be used autonomously (using import javax.swing.SwingUtilities)?

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities, invokelater

The following code executes fine:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        } ;

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
```

I am curious why the following code will not compile:

```
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        createGUI();
                    }
                } ;

                invokeLater(r);
        }
```

What is the differenc between `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);` and `import javax.swing.SwingUtilities; invokeLater(r);`

Comment: Try changing `import javax.swing.SwingUtilities` to `import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.*` and your last snippet should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reference a static member inside a class like that, as a simple name, you need a static import:

```
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.*;
```

and later you can use

```
invokeLater(r);
```

A normal import `import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;` allows you to refer to the the *class* `SwingUtilities` by a simple name, but not any of the members of that class.  So with that you could do:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
```

and

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you elaborate a bit on "a class like that"